# Is there a way of having my output in C++ displayed in a table?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ program that involves a lot looping, particularly the For loop. One of the final steps is that my output should be displayed in tabular format and I should include an option to hide the table or make it visible. I'm still rather new to C++ and thus this is new to me. Any help on this would be much appreciated.
I'm doing this on Codeblocks, so the display kinda comes via the terminal.

Comment: Printing in a table is easy. You'll want to use the `setw` output manipulator, maybe others: include <iomanip>. Make sure to draw what you want your table to look like first (use graph paper or a plain-text editor with a fixed-width font). Use a nested loop: outer loop for each row, inner loop for each column.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov can you elaborate more on the case for GUI